# Need to store data in app for sorting

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app which will give you all the businesses in a certain location.

when the user does a search on “naperville” , the app will receive a json file with:

**business names, type of business, phone #, zip code**

the user can then do further sorting on this information, such as: give me only restraunts.

what is the best approach to store this data in the app? My idea is using 3 hashmaps , example:

Hashmap1: “business name” is key and “type of business”  is value

Hashmap2: “business name” is key and “phone #”  is value

Hashmap3: “business name” is key and “zip code”  is value

This way, I can link all the information just like in a database table.“business name” works as a primary key.

because I am a new programmer, I don’t know what is the best approach…
if my approach is not good, can you recommend something better ?

Answer (score 0):

You should define an object `Business` containing `name`, `type`, `phoneNumer`, etc.

Have a single `HashMap` mapping name to `Business` or even a non mapping collection like a `List` or a `Set` depending on the behaviour you need.

You will probably want a more sophisticated search function though, for example based on distance from a certain point, etc. For those sort of things you are much better off looking for existing tools to handle it rather than trying to write your own.

Comment: can you tell me why using a object(i believe you mean a class) is better than hashmap ?

Comment: Because you group the values for one Business (name, type, phoneNumber, etc) together in one object and then only need one collection to reference them all and don't risk getting confused about what phoneNumber goes with what name